# Ransack ransortable_attributes и ransackable_associations не работают

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Я использую ransortable_attributes для установки атрибутов, доступных для сортировки. Но она не работает. То есть для сортировки все равно доступны атрибуты прописанные в ransackable_attributes. Как сделать правильно?

Второй вопрос.

Я устанавливаю ассоциации через функцию ransortable_attributes. Но в форме в функции attribute_select ассоциации не отображаются. Они отображаются только если их указать явно. Например так:

```
s.attribute_select associations: [:information, :setting]
```

Третий вопрос.

Если указывать ассоциации явно, как в предыдущем примере, то я не могу установить css класс для attribute_select.

Вот так не работает:

```
s.attribute_select associations: [:information, :setting], class: 'form-control'
```

Но вот так работает:

```
s.attribute_select Hash.new, class: 'form-control'
```

Подскажите, как исправить эти проблемы?

Код модели:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # some code

  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    %w(
      email
      current_sign_in_ip
      last_sign_in_ip
      created_at
      updated_at
    )
  end

  def self.ransortable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    %w(
      email
      created_at
      updated_at
    )
  end

  def self.ransackable_associations(auth_object = nil)
    %w(
      information
      setting
    )
  end
end
```